# python iterators, generators and in between

Tags: python, iterator, generator

So I get generator functions for lazy evaluation and generator expressions, aka generator comprehensions as its syntactic sugar equivalent.

I understand classes like

```
class Itertest1:
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 0
        self.max_repeats = 100

    def __iter__(self):
        print("in __inter__()")
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.count >= self.max_repeats:
            raise StopIteration
        self.count += 1
        print(self.count)
        return self.count
```

as a way of implementing the iterator interface, i.e. **iter**() and **next**() in one and the same class.

But what then is

```
class Itertest2:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = list(range(100))

    def __iter__(self):
        print("in __inter__()")
        for i, dp in enumerate(self.data):
            print("idx:", i)
            yield dp
```

which uses the yield statement within the **iter** member function?

Also I noticed that upon calling the iter member function

```
it = Itertest2().__iter__()
batch = it.__next__()
```

the print statement is only executed when calling **next**() for the first time.
Is this due to this weird mixture of yield and iter? I think this is quite counter intuitive...

Comment: In generator, the values are calculated lazily *i.e* values are calculated only when demanded.

Comment: (1) You should name the two classes differently, at least Itertest1 and Itertest2. (2) Itertest2 is an iterable which creates new independent iterators in its `__iter__` method. The generator function returns such an iterator. Itertest1 is an iterator which by convention returns itself in `__iter__`. E. g. Java distinguishes iterable and iterator more cleanly but less comfortably.

Comment: thanks but still, why is in "__inter__()" printed only after the first next invocation instead of the call to __iter__()?

Comment: @CD86 because the call to `__iter__` just returns your generator. Thing is, `yield` is meant to ease the process of writing iterators (among other things), there's a lot happening behind the scenes. As a result, you don't have the level of control you do when defining *both* `__iter__` **and** `__next__`; you squished them together and glued them with `yield`.

Comment: `__iter__` *itself* is a generator function, so each call to `Itertest2.__iter__` returns an independent iterator, unlike `Itertest1` where the instance of `Itertest1` itself carried the iteration state with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something equivalent to `Itertest2` could be written using a separate iterator class.

```
class Itertest3:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = list(range(100))

    def __iter__(self):
        return Itertest3Iterator(self.data)


class Itertest3Iterator:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = enumerate(data)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        print("in __inter__()")
        i, dp = next(self.state)  # Let StopIteration exception propagate
        print("idx:", i)
        return dp
```

Compare this to `Itertest1`, where the instance of `Itertest1` itself carried the state of the iteration around in it. Each call to `Itertest1.__iter__` returned the same object (the instance of `Itertest1`), so they couldn't iterate over the data independently.

Notice I put `print("in __iter__()")` in `__next__`, not `__iter__`. As you observed, nothing in a generator function actually *executes* until the first call to `__next__`. The generator function itself *only* creates an generator; it does not actually start executing the code in it.

Answer (score 1):

Having the `yield` statement anywhere in any function wraps the function code in a (native) generator object, and replaces the function with a stub that gives you said generator object.

So, here, calling `__iter__` will give you an anonymous generator object that executes the code you want.

The main use case for `__next__` is to provide a way to write an iterator without relying on (native) generators.

The use case of `__iter__` is to distinguish between an object and an iteration state over said object. Consider code like

```
c = some_iterable()
for a in c:
    for b in c:
        # do something with a and b
```

You would not want the two interleaved iterations to interfere with each other's state. This is why such a loop would desugar to something like

```
c = some_iterable()
_iter1 = iter(c)
try:
    while True:
        a = next(_iter1)
        _iter2 = iter(c)
        try:
            while True:
                b = next(_iter2)
                # do something with a and b
        except StopIteration:
            pass
 except StopIteration:
     pass
```

Typically, custom iterators implement a stub `__iter__` that returns `self`, so that `iter(iter(x))` is equivalent to `iter(x)`. This is important when writing iterator wrappers.

Comment: understood. Still, dont like this implicit deferring of the code within said member function until the rather concealed next method is called for the first time. Seems odd. So then the main use case for an __iter__ member function is to be able for the class to hold state in comparison to a pure generator function while being for concise than a full class with both __iter__ and __next__ method?